# Why is this form making the fields and variables part of the process form?

Tags: php, forms, variables, post, process

I am doing this:

```
  <form action="processform.php" type="post">
  <input type="text" name="sample">
  <input type="text" name="how">
  <input type="checkbox" name="fields" value="fields">Something</input>
  </form>
```

When the submit button is hit, this is what shows in the address bar of the process page:

```
  https://www.domain.com/processform.php?sample=&how=&fields=
```

Comment: can you show your processform.php? are you using $_GET there?

Comment: As the answers say you should change it to method="post". By default the from method is GET - hence your fields in the address bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to `<form method="post" />`

Answer (score 2):

change `type="post"` to `method="post"` for starters

Answer (score 1):

The `method` attribute specifies the submission type (e.g. "get" or "post"), but you've used the `type` attribute...and this is incorrect. You need something like:

```
<form action="processform.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="sample">
 <input type="text" name="how">
 <input type="checkbox" name="fields" value="fields">Something</input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is wrong

Try

```
<form action="processform.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="sample" value='VALUE' />
   <input type="text" name="how" value='VALUE' />

   <label for='fields'>Something</label>
   <input id='fields' type="checkbox" name="fields" value="Something" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<form action="processform.php" method="post">`

`type` needs to be `method`